# EntityFarmeworkCore абстрактный слой доступа к данным

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Здравсвуйте, хотелось создать абстрактный слой доступа к данным используя проекты типа NetStandart 2.0

Думаю использовать один проект: работа с данными "DAL", в котором будут зависимости от EntityFarmeworkCore.
В нем будет находится Context и Entities. Также обертка в виде обобщенного репозиория.

Второй проект бизнес логики "BL". зависимость от "DAL".
Набор конкретных методов которые работают с данными репозиториев.
Например:
 IList GetAllDepartments()
 Department GetDepartmentByName(string departmentName)

Начал искать похожие реализации и наткнулся на скачанную статью где описывается подобная архитектура (ссылку на статью не помню).
Суть подхода в том, что в репозитории на каждое атомарное действие создается короткоживущий контекст, по сути без отслеживания трекинга изменений,
методы репозитория возвращают не запрос Iquereble, а сразу IList. Слой бизнес логики использует эти методы, предоставляя понятный интерфейс наружу.

Реализовал тестовый пример и возникли вопросы правильно ли я все делаю.
Привожу пример кода где используются всего 2 сущности Department и Employee.

Entities:

```
public interface IEntitie
{
   int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Department : IEntitie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new HashSet<Employee>();
}

public class Employee : IEntitie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new HashSet<Address>();
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class Context : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    #region Reps

    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employes { get; set; }

    #endregion


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var service = new GetConnectionStringService(); //получение строки подключения
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(service.Connection);
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //явное описание связи 1 ко многим
        //Employee < --> Departments One2Many----------------------------
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Department)
            .WithMany(s => s.Employees)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.DepartmentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
    IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
    T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
    void Add(params T[] items);
    void Update(params T[] items);
    void Remove(params T[] items);
}


public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            list = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where,
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            list = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(where)
                .ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public virtual T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where,
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        T item = null;
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            item = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking() //Don't track any changes for the selected item
                .FirstOrDefault(where); //Apply where clause
        }
        return item;
    }

    public virtual void Add(params T[] items)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Remove(params T[] items)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


конкретные репозитории, если нужны специфические свойства или переопределение virtual методов

public interface IDepartmentRepository : IGenericDataRepository<Department>
{
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository : IGenericDataRepository<Employee>
{
}

public interface IAdressRepository : IGenericDataRepository<Address>
{
}


public class DepartmentRepository : GenericDataRepository<Department>, IDepartmentRepository
{
}

public class EmployeeRepository : GenericDataRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
}

public class AddressRepository : GenericDataRepository<Address>, IAdressRepository
{
}
```

интерфейс бизнес логики:

```
public interface IBusinessLayer
{
    IList<Department> GetAllDepartments();
    Department GetDepartmentByName(string departmentName);
    void AddDepartment(params Department[] departments);
    void UpdateDepartment(params Department[] departments);
    void RemoveDepartment(params Department[] departments);

    IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartmentName(string departmentName);
    void AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    void UpdateEmploee(Employee employee);
    void RemoveEmployee(Employee employee);
    Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeId);
}
```

реализация бизнес логики:

```
public class BuinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    private readonly IDepartmentRepository _deptRepository;
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    private readonly IAdressRepository _adressRepository;


    #region ctor

    public BuinessLayer()
    {
        _deptRepository = new DepartmentRepository();
        _employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
        _adressRepository= new AddressRepository();
    }


    public BuinessLayer(IDepartmentRepository deptRepository,
        IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _deptRepository = deptRepository;
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    #endregion




    public IList<Department> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        return _deptRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public Department GetDepartmentByName(string departmentName)
    {
        return _deptRepository.GetSingle(
            d => d.Name.Equals(departmentName),
            d => d.Employees); //include related employees
    }

    public void AddDepartment(params Department[] departments)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _deptRepository.Add(departments);
    }

    public void UpdateDepartment(params Department[] departments)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _deptRepository.Update(departments);
    }

    public void RemoveDepartment(params Department[] departments)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _deptRepository.Remove(departments);
    }

    public IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartmentName(string departmentName)
    {
        return _employeeRepository.GetList(e => e.Department.Name.Equals(departmentName));
    }

    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _employeeRepository.Add(employee);
    }

    public void UpdateEmploee(Employee employee)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _employeeRepository.Update(employee);
    }

    public void RemoveEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        /* Validation and error handling omitted */
        _employeeRepository.Remove(employee);
    }


    public Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeId)
    {
        return _employeeRepository.GetSingle(
            d => d.Id.Equals(employeeId),
            d => d.Addresses); //include related employees
    }
}
```

ВОПРОСЫ:

1. я так понимаю слой BL включает в себя нужные репозитории, из которых можно получить(загрузить)связанные данные.
   на набор всего из 2-ух сушностей такое большое кол-во методов в IBusinessLayer, это немного напрягает.
2. Пример приведенн всего с одной связью 1 ко многим, а если будет глубина зависимостей больше, например у Employee появится набор адрессов (1 ко многим с таблицей адресов)
   тогда каким образом можно указать такую вложенность в методе репозитория с указанием navigationProperties?
   Необходимо явно указать .ThenInclude() и передать зависимое свойство, как это сделать например в GetAll?

   ```
   public virtual IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
   {
       List<T> list;
       using (var context = new Context())
       {
           IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();


           foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
               dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty); //???

           list = dbQuery
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToList<T>();
       }
       return list;
   }
   ```

И как быть с реализацией многие ко многим которая разбивается на 2 реализации 1 ко многим. 
может я плохо понимаю как задавать Expression?

3. Может такая архитектура и расчитанна на атомарные (отдельные) действия, например вытащили из базы Отдел и всех сотрудников, далее если нужны адресса вытаскиваем для каждого сотрудника список его адресов.
   Но это ведь жутко не оптимально, стольбко запросов отделных?

Может кто-то работал с подобным подходом прошу высказать свои мысли.
Я бы сделал классическую реализацию репозитория возвращающую IQuereble и уже в методах бизнес логики составлял запросы (с необходимой глубиной вложенности), но методов в слое бизнес логики было бы опять много...

Comment: Недостаток репозитория в больших и развивающихся проектах в том, что он постепенно превращается в этакий статический класс (без `static`). Добавляются новые запросы по новым критериям, новые апдейты, и т.д. Поэтому некоторые сразу решают перейти на CQRS, т.е. производят разделение на Queries (возвращают результат) & Commans (ничего не возвращают, но изменяют данные). Каждый запрос или команда представляет собой коротко  живущий объект, создаваемый в момент необходимой работы с БД. Вот [отличный доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvIXCgwGf9E) на эту тему.

Comment: Спасибо, гляну!

Comment: Рекомендую сразу сделать интерфейс ```IEntity``` универсальным: ```interface IEntity<T> { T id {get; set; }}```. Иначе потом, если появятся таблицы с ключами типа long, string, guid или, прости господи, с составными ключами - будет больно.

Answer (score 0):

Подход, описанный выше вполне оправдан, не рекомендовал бы возвращать IQueryable, поскольку каждый слой должен инкапсулировать свою логику от внешнего мира, перенос части логики DAL нарушает само понятие разделения на слои. 
К примеру, в какой то момент вы решили некоторые запросы перенести на Dapper(или другой микро-ORM) для увеличения производительности, однако вам придется менять:

1. метод бизнес логики
2. метод логики данных
3. возвращаемый тип метода(хотя может и возможно IEnumerable привести к IQueryable, но по мне это извращенство)

Да, кол-во методов будет расти с ростом вашего приложения, этого никак не избежать (понимаю стремление к идеалу архитектуры, но такого, увы, не найти). Выше в комментариях привели CQRS, но в этом случае будет расти кол-во классов(причем со скоростью, гораздо большей, чем кол-во репозиториев).

Comment: Спасибо. Почитал и послушал про CQRS, к этому надо прийти прочувствовав недостатки решения с репозиторем, просто так начать делать вредили подучиться что то хорошее. Хотел у вас спросить а как быть с методом  GetAll репозитория, если нужно вернуть объекты с N уровнем вложенности, т.е. использовать ThenInclude(p=> p.IncludeProperty).

Comment: @Aldmi если я правильно вопрос понял...допустим у вас есть базовый абстрактный репозиторий, наследуете от него конкретный репозиторий, если в базовом есть метод GetAll, то можно пометить его как virtual и переопределить(override) в любом конкретном репозитории

Comment: Да правильно поняли, если функционал надо дополнить или переопределить, то это можно сделать в конкретном репозитории. Только у меня прикладной вопрос как сделать метод на подобии GetAll, более универсальным, чтобы можно было указывать N уровень вложенности извлекаемых данных